# How do you override the Spark Java heap size?

Tags: apache-spark

We are running Spark drivers and executors in Docker containers, orchestrated by Kubernetes.  We'd like to be able to set the Java heap size for them at runtime, via the Kubernetes controller YAML.  
What  Spark config has to be set to do this?  If I do nothing and look at the launched process via `ps -ef`, I see:

```
root       639   638  0 00:16 ?        00:00:23 /opt/ibm/java/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/ibm/spark/conf/:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/ibm/hadoop/conf/ -Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=172.17.48.29:2181,172.17.231.2:2181,172.17.47.17:2181 -Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=172.17.48.29:2181,172.17.231.2:2181,172.17.47.17:2181 -Dcom.ibm.apm.spark.logfilename=master.log -Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=2 **-Xms1g -Xmx1g** org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip sparkmaster-1 --port 7077 --webui-port 18080
```

Something is setting the -Xms and -Xmx options.  I tried setting `SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-XmsIG -Xms2G"` in `spark-env.sh` and got:

```
root      2919  2917  2 19:16 ?        00:00:15 /opt/ibm/java/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/ibm/spark/conf/:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/ibm/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/ibm/hadoop/conf/ -Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=172.17.48.29:2181,172.17.231.2:2181,172.17.47.17:2181 **-Xms1G -Xmx2G** -Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=172.17.48.29:2181,172.17.231.2:2181,172.17.47.17:2181 **-Xms1G -Xmx2G** -Dcom.ibm.apm.spark.logfilename=master.log -Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=2 **-Xms1g -Xmx1g** org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip sparkmaster-1 --port 7077 --webui-port 18080
```

A friend suggested setting

spark.driver.memory 2g

in `spark-defaults.conf`, but the results looked like the first example.  Maybe the values in the `ps -ef` command were overridden by this setting, but how would I know?  If `spark.driver.memory` is the right override, can you set the heap min and max this way, or does this just set the max?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY`?

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setting [`SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY` environment variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) in `conf/spark-env.sh` should do the trick:

> `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY`     Memory to allocate to the Spark master and worker daemons themselves (default: 1g).